# SquareSpace Header Injection Code

Tags: squarespace

On a SquareSpace Blog (in the settings) there is a section for PAGE HEADER INJECTION CODE.

It then puts whatever you place here in the header of the blog summary page and all posts.

I'm wondering if its possible to be able to inject header code ONLY for individual posts and not the blog summary page ?

Answer (score 1):

This can most certainly be done!

For the individual pages you want custom header content, you can add a **code block at the top of the page.**

Then you can make your **individual html header**. For instance, this is the code I used to load jQuery for a single page:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You will get a notification on the code block, saying the injected code will only be available for that page.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in developer mode, you can add this JQuery into the javascript files locally, use sublime text editor with smpt to access your squarespace locally, then within the solution you can add the code into the javascript files, When I did this I had to add jquery to the solution as it didn't have JQuery only javascript.

But not to sure as to why you want code just in the individual posts, squarespace works by loading all the javascript and css when the original server call is made.

The only way i suggest you doing this is to add c code block each to the post, so you will have a code block for each page. http://help.squarespace.com/guides/about-the-code-block